# Should rejection/approval of suggested edit done by a user who doesn't have knowledge of that particular technology

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I suggest that people who don't provide any answer to the related tag of a question should not have the privilege to approve or reject suggested edits to that question.

For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3764919).

In this suggested edit the user who rejected the edit hadn't provided any answer to the related tag.

Comment: This certainly isn't a bug. I've changed it to a support/feature-request question. However your title doesn't match the body. Are you asking whether it's possible or are you requesting for it to be changed? Could you please clarify?

Comment: As I mention I have this one as suggestion and question also.

Comment: You shouldn't  be suggesting edits that require technical expertise to approve anyways.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to be a subject matter expert to be able to review edits for validity, in general.

If an edit modifies things over the reviewer's head or outside of their realm of knowledge, any reviewer that's actually being careful is going to **hit the Skip button**.

I personally might have rejected that edit because it adds new information to the post that seems like it should, instead, be added as a comment.  I also might have skipped it, because I know I don't know enough to judge it on its own.

Do note that roboreviewers are gonna roboreview no matter what.  Adding a tag participation gateway will only stop good reviewers, not roboreviewers.

Comment: so according to you I have to create a new answer for that question while I can provide the answer by a little editing in the existing one...

is it good?

and users didn't use skip button a lot because there are badges on the number of reviews..

Comment: @charles are you suggesting that people that reject information additions rather than skipping are robots?

Comment: @urfusion, there is not much harm in expanding and improving upon someone else's answer in your own answer -- with attribution -- especially if you believe that the answer glosses over important technical details that you can *greatly* expand upon.  It is usually more appropriate to simply add such things as comments when it's merely adding a small note, such as you did here.  The person that wrote the answer may choose to update their own question based on those comments.

Comment: @JanDvorak, IMO reviewers that blindly reject a technical improvement that has content outside of their area of experience are doing the site no favors.  Are they roboreviewing?  No, but it's still an unfortunate, relatively minor problem.

Answer (score 6):

As Charles notes in his answer, you don't have to be a subject matter expert to check whether an edit at least makes basic grammatical sense.  Yours doesn't.

For convenience, here's the edit you tried to make (with the part added by you in **bold**):

> If you try to access the store using a domain other than the one configured in core_config_data, Magento will attempt to redirect you, which I think is what you're experiencing **and empty log_url ,log_url_info, tables from databse and delete files from var/cache, var/session**.

Just at a glance, even without knowing anything about Magento, I see:

- a misplaced comma,
- a misspelled word ("databse"), and
- a run-on sentence with completely broken grammar.  (Did you even *read* what the existing sentence was saying, before you tacked your additions onto it?)

Now, if this had been your *own* answer, that would've been fine — maybe it wouldn't have earned quite as many upvotes as if it had been better written, but even so, any sloppy writing in your own answer wouldn't really have harmed anyone else.

However, edits to *other people's answers* are generally held to a higher standard: you're basically taking someone else's careful work and scribbling on top of it, and so the general standard for approval (robo-approvers excluded) is that your edit must be *a clear and obvious improvement* upon the existing answer in every respect, and at least must not make the answer *worse* in any way.

Generally, if you think that an answer is missing some important details, but you don't feel your English skills are at the level you'd need to match or exceed the writing quality of the existing answer, you're probably better off describing the missing details in a comment.  The author of the answer can then, if they wish, incorporate the information into their answer properly; and, even if they don't, your comment will be publicly visible, providing the missing information to other readers.